# Python to C++ code

Tags: c++, python

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *

bits=np.array([ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
print(bits)
N_bits=len(bits)
print(N_bits)
N_S=(N_bits/4)+1


delta1=zeros(((N_bits/4)+1,) , dtype=np.complex)
delta2=zeros(((N_bits/4)+1,) , dtype=np.complex)

k=1

C=zeros(((N_bits/4)+1,) , dtype=np.complex)
D=zeros(((N_bits/4)+1,) , dtype=np.complex)

C[0]=2+2j
D[0]=1+1j
```

please tell me what would be the equivalent C++ code

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Comment: We are not doing your homework without having seen any effort and motivation

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::vector to represent arrays.

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

int numElements = 42;
std::vector<std::complex<double> > x(numElements, 0);

double realPart = 23;
double imgPart = 0;
x.at(0) = std::complex<double>(realPart, imgPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this..

```
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nbits=16;
    vector<complex<float> > arr;
    for(int i=0; i<nbits; i++ )
    {
    arr.push_back(complex<float>(0,0) );
    }
    arr.at(3).real()=5.2;
    arr.at(3).imag()=6.3;
    cout << arr[3] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`arr.push_back(complex<float>(0,0) );`

is to initialize every element to zero and build the array
        arr.at(3).real()=5.2;
        arr.at(3).imag()=6.3;
is to assign values to an element of the array or better yet

`arr.at(5)=complex<float> (1,-2);`

to obtain the same result. Finally:

`cout << arr[3] << endl;`

to print an element of the array

Comment: Note there is no need for the loop. You can say `std::vector<complex<float>>(nbits);`